# Creating a new sheet, copying data and naming the sheet

Tags: vba, excel, range, spreadsheet

I need help!

I am looking to create a button that will create a new worksheet, copying the data that has been inputted and naming the sheet the value which is entered in F5.

I have this so far:

```
Sub CreateNewSheet()
sheet_name_to_create = Sheet1.Range("F5").Value

For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) = LCase(sheet_name_to_create) Then
MsgBox "Already Exists!"
Exit Sub
End If
Next
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = sheet_name_to_create

End Sub
```

This is creating the new sheet for me, naming it the value which is in F5.
But I need to copy the range C4:G17

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub copy_newsheet()

Dim pname
Dim ws As Worksheet

pname = ActiveSheet.Range("F5").Value

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

If ws.Name = pname Then
MsgBox "Already Exists"
Exit Sub
End If

Next ws

ActiveSheet.Range("C4:G17").Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Range("C4:G17").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Range("C4:G17").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
ActiveSheet.Name = pname

End Sub
```

Comment: BOOOOOOMMM! THHANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

you can try next code:

```
Sub CreateNewSheet()
sheet_name_to_create = Sheet1.Range("F5").Value
Sheet1.Range("C4:G17").Copy 

For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) = LCase(sheet_name_to_create) Then
MsgBox "Already Exists!"
Exit Sub
End If
Next
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = sheet_name_to_create
Sheets(sheet_name_to_create).Range("C4:G17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried, but it is still not moving the data over??